# Signed/unsigned mismatch

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I'm having hard time understanding nature of issue I encountered in my code.
Line

```
if ((struct.c == 0x02) && (struct2.c == 0x02) && (struct.s == !struct2.s))
    {/**/}
```

where `c` is `int` and `s` is `uint64_t` produces

> C4388:'==' signed/unsigned mismatch

warning. I understand what that warning is, I can't see what is triggering it here. What am I missing?

Comment: `struct` is a reserved keyword in C. I wouldn't recommend using it as the name of a variable.

Comment: That's only for illustration purpose

Comment: and this is a C code, right?

Comment: Yes, it happens to be

Comment: ["If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to the value one of the destination type"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), "Numeric conversions". I presume that would result in destination type `uint64_t`, making the question C-only. Why add the C++-tag then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Directly quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.3.3, (*emphasis mine*)

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is `0` if the value of its operand compares
>   unequal to `0`, `1` if the value of its operand compares equal to `0`. **The result has type `int`**....

So, the result of the logical `!` operator is `int`, so `!struct2.s` produces `int` value, and the expression

```
....(struct.s == !struct2.s)
```

creates the issue.

---

NOTE 1:

I guess you use `struct` as a structure name just for illustration purpose, otherwise, `struct` being a reserved keyword in `C` you cannot use that as a variable name.

---

NOTE 2:

Maybe what you actually meant is `(struct.s != struct2.s)`, but that's also just a (*probable*)guess.

---

<sup>FOOTNOTE :: Earlier question tagged C++ also, Moving it as footnote but keeping the info just for reference.</sup>
<sup>Regarding `C++`, the return type of `!` is `bool`. Ref: `C++11`, chapter § 5.3.3 (again, emphasis mine)</sup>

> <sup>The operand of the logical negation operator `!` is contextually converted to  bool`(Clause 4); its value is`true`if the converted operand is`false`and  false` otherwise. **The type of the result is `bool`.**</sup>

Comment: @JensGustedt Was just adding that, though as a note. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. As for the intent of the operation, `struct.s == !struct2.s` was exactly what I was going for, but thanks for caring :)

Comment: Does negation also yield `int` for C++? Or would that be `bool` there?

Answer (score 1):

[too long for a comment]

To get the most out of compiler warnings, always try to put only one statement/expression on one line (at least temporarily when trying to determine the error's/warning's source).

So if you'd have set the code this way:

```
if (
    (struct.c == 0x02) 
    && (struct2.c == 0x02) 
    && (struct.s == !struct2.s)
  )
```

You'd been pointed by the compiler to exactly the (relativly) 4th line.